# can't reference a custom function in a CHECK CONSTRAINT

Tags: oracle, triggers, stored-functions, check-constraints

i have a table with a column that has to be less than a certain value, the problem is this value is stored in another table so i cannot reference it so after some research i found out that i can use a function and call it in the check CONSTRAINT, here is my function

```
create or replace FUNCTION check_caution(id_cont in NUMBER)
return number
as res number ;
begin
select amount_contract*caution_offre_f*0.01 into res from contract 
where id_contract=id_cont;
return res;
end check_caution;
```

the function works fine and i tested it.
and here is my CHECK CONSTRAINT

```
alter table caution_exe 
add CONSTRAINT check_amount
check (caution_exe.amount_caution<=check_caution(caution_exe.id_contract));
```

but this is the message i get after i try to add it

```
ORA-00904: "CHECK_CAUTION": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Comment: This is simply not possible in Oracle

Comment: Documented restriction: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52205

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can't reference your own function in `check` constraint, create a **trigger** which will do that job. Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_biu_cauexe
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON caution_exe
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF :new.amount_caution <= check_caution (:new.caution_exe.id_contract)
   THEN
      raise_application_error (-20000, 'Not allowed');
   END IF;
END;
```